# save attributes from same entity from two different view controllers, only 1 updating to new cells

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data

[Image of Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTEC1.png)

I am trying to update different attributes in one entity from different view controllers.

Say I have the entity person open, one view controller will take the persons name email etc, the other view controller has the next time you will meet that person and activities you do with that person open.

Both should save to their respective attributes for the same entity. As it stands I can only get the first viewcontrollers info saving to new cells then the second one only saves to one cell no matter how many cells are saved with the first view controller

@interface PeopleDetailViewControllerUIViewController ()

```
@end

@implementation PeopleDetailViewControllerUIViewController
@synthesize people;
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (self.people) {
        [self.nameTextField setText:[self.people valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.emailTextField setText:[self.people valueForKey:@"email"]];
        [self.homeTextField setText:[self.people valueForKey:@"home"]];
        [self.cellTextField setText:[self.people valueForKey:@"cell"]];
        [self.addressTextField setText:[self.people valueForKey:@"address"]];
        [self.notesTextField setText:[self.people valueForKey:@"notes"]];
     }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    #pragma mark - Table view data source


        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView         cellForRowAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
             {
               static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
                 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

            // Configure the cell...

                 return cell;
            } 

            /*

}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}    


 - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

         // Create a new managed object
     if (self.people) {
        [self.people setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
         [self.people setValue:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
         [self.people setValue:self.homeTextField.text forKey:@"home"];
         [self.people setValue:self.cellTextField.text forKey:@"cell"];
         [self.people setValue:self.addressTextField.text forKey:@"address"];
         [self.people setValue:self.notesTextField.text forKey:@"notes"];
    }
    else{
        NSManagedObject *newPeople = [NSEntityDescription     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newPerson setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.homeTextField.text forKey:@"home"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.cellTextField.text forKey:@"cell"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.addressTextField.text forKey:@"address"];
        [newPerson setValue:self.notesTextField.text forKey:@"notes"];
    }


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
     }

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Comment: How is this different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530285/coredata-issue-save-attributes-from-same-entity-from-two-different-view-contro?

Comment: @MartinR I got the data saving but it won't save to new tableview cells only the first tableview cell